# import numpy using python 2.7 on windows

Tags: python, import

I tried:

```
import numpy as np
```

but the following error appears:

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I already installed numpy:

```
conda install numpy
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda:
#
numpy                     1.9.2                    py27_0
```

What might be the problem here?

Comment: If u r using window, then u can try this installer..http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/

Comment: How are you running your scripts? The problem seems to be that when you run the script, you are not using Anaconda's version of Python but a previously installed version. Anurag's suggestion will not help if that's the case.

Comment: I installed ipython and now I have fixed the problem. Probably it was what Marius suggested,  still when running the script as python the problems remains.

Comment: How would I do to make powershell call Anaconda's version of python instead of the previously installed python? I already changed de path environment but still calls the previous installed